# Android: Setting locale programmatically in the new way alters context

Tags: android, internationalization, locale, android-context

I know there is a lot of discussion about this topic, and I have done my homework and previously read many stackoverflow posts but none of them seems solve my problem.

I have a setLocale function that launch on every activity onCreate (not sure if its the best way to do it but is the way I'm doing it right now) and setLocale creates and returns a new context with custom locale configuration applied and it works (when you call getString the text in the correct language is return), but the fact is that this new context (context = context.createConfigurationContext(config) in setLocale) is of type **ContextImpl?** and what I expect it to be is the Activity which called setLocale, because I then run methods that need an activity in context (a context of type activity) but as it's ContextImpl I get "Cannot cast android.app.ContextImpl to Activity". Is it clear? Any help?

Thanks.

```
public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {

        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        return context;
    }
```

Edit 1: One good approach.

If I insert the next piece of code in my SplashScreen activity:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Then the locale works alongside the whole app but I know **UpdateConfiguration is deprecated** and I'm trying to use the new format that could be:

```
public static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {

        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 17) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        return context;
    }
```

But with this second updated approach it is not working, any suggestions?

Comment: "what I expect it to be is the Activity which called setLocale" – Well, it won't be. The `Context` passed to `createConfigurationContext()` is wrapped in another `Context`, specifically a `ContextImpl`. "because I then run methods that need an activity in context (a context of type activity)" – You already have the `Activity` itself. Can't you just use that for those methods?

Comment: Why don't you just set the locale once in the Application class?

Comment: Good point @lionscribe, I honestly didn't realize but if I think it is nonsese to set the locale in every activity onCreate. I'll try your suggestion and let you know. Anyway, the problem I am mentioning, that context = context.createConfigurationContext(config); alters context creating a new object of type ContextImpl will still remain :s

Comment: Thank you for your time @Mike M. You are right, I could use the activity itself for calling those methods but as my app is designed so far I set a context class object of each activity and use it along all activity wherever it is needed and those methods are distributed along some helper classes so it would be difficult and tedious to chamge (and identify) such a big amount of method calls.

Comment: @Mike M. Now, with this solution (that works fine regarding picking the correct language texts) the problem is setLocale alters my context at the very beginning of activity creation so whenever I need to cast that context to activity it throws an exception. In the paso it was working fine because I was using setLocale in the old fashion way without context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);

Comment: Once you setLocale in Application, you should not have any need to call createConfigurationContext

Comment: Thank you @lionscribe. You pointed me in the right direction, now I'm updating locale in SplashScreen activity (which is called only once when app starts) and not in every activity (nonsense) but see my recent edit because I'm facing a little problem with this, it is working using the "old style" way of setting locale, but not the current updated one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long investigation, I'll answer myself with what I have concluded is the optimal (and up to date) solution to set locale globally in the current way.

I have created a ContextWrapper class as follows:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;

import com.testmepracticetool.toeflsatactexamprep.helpers.TMLocale;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

    public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context) {

        String language = TMLocale.getLocale(context);

        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        Locale sysLocale = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
        } else {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
        }
        if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }

        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return new MyContextWrapper(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config){
        return config.locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config){
        return config.getLocales().get(0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale){
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale){
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```

This class will create a context with the specified language injected which will be later attached into current activity as context with the following method:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

This should be inserted on every activity but what I've ended up doing to make it even simpler and better is to create a BaseActivity class and every activity extends that.

This way we set the locale in the up to date and preferred way and it works, when you do a getString the correct language is picked up.

Hope my investigation helps anyone else having the same problem.

Comment: Hi! I used your code, but I'm still having the same issue. I get "Cannot cast android.app.ContextImpl to Activity" inside the `onReceive` event of a `BroadcastReceiver`. Any idea why that could be happening?